# WPF MVVM StatusBar Animation

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, mvvm, storyboard

I have a StatusBar object with Brush color and text properties.
This StatusBar has another boolean property - IsStatusCollapsed, when this property set to false the StatsBar is displayed :

```
    private bool _isStatusCollapsed = true;
    public bool IsStatusCollapsed
    {
        get
        {
            return _isStatusCollapsed;
        }
        set
        {
            _isStatusCollapsed = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsStatusCollapsed");
        }
    }
```

Here is the xaml:

```
 <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Visibility="{Binding          
       Path=StatusBar.IsStatusCollapsed, 
       Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
       <Rectangle MinHeight="30" Fill="{Binding         
       StatusBar.StatusBackgroundBrush}" />
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusBar.StatusMessage}"      
       TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
       Padding="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
  </Grid>
```

The Grid Visibility property uses a converter to show or collapse the StatusBar.

I want to perform animation in a way that the StatusBar will be entered from bottom to top and will disappear from top to bottom instead of just appear\disappear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<Grid  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" >
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding StatusBar.StatusBackgroundBrush}" MinHeight="30" Height="0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusBar.StatusMessage}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" Margin="10,0,0,0" Padding="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
        <Button Content="X" Padding="5" Command="{Binding Run}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"/>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RunStoryboard}" Value="False">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Height)" 
                                        From="30" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Height)" 
                                        From="0" To="30" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
    </Grid>
```